# How to Invoke web service async method to windows form application?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I Have Written firebase database insertion code in web service and declared the method in web service as asynchronous. Now I want to call that async method in my windows form application button click event.

This is What i have tried:

Code for web service:

```
namespace Webservice
{
    public class FireService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public async Task Insert()
        {
            mainform = new Form1();
            SetResponse response = await 
            client.SetTaskAsync("Employee/"+mainform.txt_EID.Text,
            Data.Instance.InsertInfo());
            StudentData student = response.ResultAs<StudentData>();
        }
    }
}
```

Code for WinForm Application:

```
namespace FirebaseCRUD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FireService1SoapClient obj = new FireService1SoapClient();
        private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await obj.Insert();
        }
    }

}
```

I Want Insert() method to be invoked into insert button click event.But i am not getting the name of method when i try to call,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you instantiate new Form1() inside the web method?

Comment: Actually I want Textbox data from Windows Form which is in different project To Web Service method thats why i created an instance of form1

Comment: You need to pass the data that the service needs as *parameters* when you call the service. The service has no way of even knowing *what program called it*, let alone access to data that resides inside that program's process.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use `Task and async/await` with legacy technology like `System.Web.Services.WebService` since it was designed before `async/await` was introduced. These WebServices doesn't work properly with it. I recommend you to look at `Asp.Net Core` or at least `WCF` instead of `System.Web.Services.WebService`. Also you need to make a decision where asynchrony will be(on client side, on server side or both).

But if it is not production code, probably `FireService1SoapClient` generated async methods in "old style" with BeginXXX and EndXXX prefixes and you need to call `obj.BeginInsert` without `await` keyword.

Comment: Might be worth linking off to the [Interop with Other Asynchronous Patterns and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types) document which discusses how to put wrappers around APM methods (BeginXXX and EndXXX) and be able to use `Task` and async goodness again.